# Find offset to parameter not listed in objdump in vmlinux (which contains debug symbols)

Tags: ghidra, linux, objdump

I have a series of address offsets for ubuntu that are used in a custom toolset. I'd like to build a set of offsets for another kernel, but I can't find some ubuntu offset addresses in the debug symbols, so I can't determine what my new kernel offsets should point at.

Some of the offsets do point at symbols. For example, kernel base `0xffffffff81000000` + offset `0xa000c0` = `0xffffffff81a000c0`, which has symbol `linux_banner` in the vmlinux objdump. I can also find this symbol in Ghidra (Navigation > Go To).

However, most do not point to symbols. For example, base `0xffffffff81000000` + offset `0x5d8` = `0xffffffff810005d8`, which is not found in the objdump. In Ghidra, this points me to a line `...fff810005d8 90   ??   90h`.

The nearest symbol in memory for most of these mystery offsets, according to the objdump, is `.text` or `_stext`. I suspect these mystery offsets point to parameters passed to these functions.

How can I find what this offset points at, so that I can create a new offset to the same 'symbol' for another kernel?